# async await anonymous login on Firebase does not wait for user registration

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I have a Vue app in which I have the following snippet for handling anonymous sign in's to my website. This is basically inside created() hook.

The pattern here is recommended by Firebase itself in documentation.

```
async created() {
    app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (curUser) => {
        if (!curUser) {
            console.log('auth state change triggered. NO current user');
            await app.auth().signInAnonymously().catch((error) => {
                // Handle Errors here.
                let errorCode = error.code;
                let errorMessage = error.message;
                console.log("Error: " + errorCode + errorMessage)
            });
            const curUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            console.log('curUser after anon sign in: ', curUser.uid);
        }
        else {
            console.log('current user: ', curUser.uid)
        }
    }
}
```

So this one is triggered when user enters the site first time. Later in another place, the user signs in with Google Auth.

My issue starts when user signs out of Google Auth with `auth().signOut();` The `onAuthStateChanged()` is triggered and user is signed in TWICE.

When I do the following actions;

- enter the site (get anonymous sign in uuid as per the code)
- sign in with Google Auth (get Google Auth)
- sign out from Google Auth (trigger async created() {
  auth().onAuthStateChanged())

Console prints the following:

```
current user:  O8CxixbNhmZPfrtoVC7cX5S5GmC3
current user:  SDI689qRCZWhxJ7VoZJF75Ouazy2
auth state change triggered. NO current user
current user:  Q2vjaZE0ljThMot1GtOUlDwR4BE2
curUser after anon sign in:  Q2vjaZE0ljThMot1GtOUlDwR4BE2
current user:  ziGpZf7aUwU6hXYvaAHfBD1fmnu2
```

The first uuid(`5GmC3`) is the first anon uuid, the second (`Ouazy2`) from Google Auth. As you can see logging off from Google triggers auth().onAuthStateChanged() three times. First it gets `Q2vjaZE0ljThMot1GtOUlDwR4BE2` from by testing true in `if` and then testing if condition false TWICE, it prints two different uuid's. I made sure I am not calling auth().signInAnonymously() any where else.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: are you sure `console.log('curUser after anon sign in: ', curUser);` outputs anything but `null` (or another falsy value) - because that can't happen since that code runs only if `curUser` is falsy - please check the console output carefully

Comment: My apologies. While cleaning, I deleted one line extra: `const curUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;` I will add it above now.

Comment: that code won't run ... you can't declare a `const` with the same name as a function parameter - no, wait, it's in an if block, my mistake

Comment: yeah, it does unfortunately. I just edited to add console logs above.